# Declare a `char` to pass to a function

Tags: c++

Sorry, this is a really simple question but I can't find the answer...I have implemented a **char stack** with a **push** function that takes in a char to push into the stack. However, I don't know how to actually declare a char to push into the stack.

I've tried doing this, but I get an error saying that I'm trying to convert from a const char* to a char:

```
int main(){
    char_stack stack;
    char c = "x";
    s1.push(c);
}
```

I've also tried doing this, but I think that's making c into a char*, and since my push function takes in only chars, I get another error.

```
int main(){
    char_stack s1;
    char c[] = "p";
    s1.push(c);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You need single quotes: `char c = 'x';` And change your question to "how do I declare a char?" This has nothing to do with your stack.

Comment: .....thank you...LOL. And I just started back on programming again, so I forgot a lot of things, but still remember concepts like stacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to go is:

```
char c = 'p';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `char c = 'x';`. What you are trying is defining a string (char array) and assigning to char variable.